# Python3 - Delete Top Rows from CSV before headers

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that is a vulnerability report and at the top of the csv is 4 rows of with one to two columns of text about the report before the headers. I am trying to write a script that will delete these rows so that I can combine multiple files for calculations, reporting etc.

I have tried using pandas to convert the csv into a dataframe and then delete the rows, but because these top rows are not headers the dataframe conversion fails. Any advice on how I can delete these top four rows from the csv? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example or more detailed explanation with your code. Kindly refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use the `skiprows` parameter of read_csv. For example:

```py
# Skip 2 rows from top in csv and initialize a dataframe
usersDf = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skiprows=2)

# Skip  rows at specific index
usersDf = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skiprows=[0,2,5])
```